# How do I download libappindicator1?

Tags: debian, chrome-book

I want to download discord-ptb-0.0.29.deb on my Chromebook (it has Linux, `Debian GNU/Linux 11 \n \l` to be exact), but it met me with this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  discord-ptb: Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installable
```

How do I download libappindicator1? I've looked at other questions and didn't find the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I download libappindicator1?

Your package manager will download `libappindicator1` by itself, but the problem is a different one: If you **downloaded** a deb file from somewhere, it will likely have the wrong dependencies, which causes the

```
Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installable
```

error. So instead of downloading the deb, use the package manager of whatever distro you installed on your Chromebook (`apt` is a good guess) to select and install the package you want. Then it will download the right `.deb` file for you, and be able to resolve dependencies.

---

If you've Debian, you have the choice between several package managers. You can easily [read up](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_basic_package_management_operations) on this on the Internet. I personally use `apt-get`, because it was the first one, and occasionaly `aptitude` if I need a UI.

So if I wanted to install `libappindicator1`, I'd first search for it:

```
$ apt-cache search libappindicator1
libappindicator1 - allow applications to export a menu into the panel
```

and then I'd install it

```
$ sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Note the `sudo`, because I need root (superuser) permissions to install something, and the `$` prompt indicates I am a normal user, but I've set up `sudo` to give me root permissions if I need them. If you see a `#` prompt, you are already root.

From time to time you also need to update your local view of the available packages, you do this with

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

That's the first thing you need to do if you haven't done it.

---

But that's not how I'd do it, because that's just a dependency. Instead, I'd search for Discord:

```
$ apt-get search discord
```

On my system, it doesn't find it. Next I'd google for "debian discord", which shows me that they are not integrated into distros, but just provides a deb file, and for Debian, that is called `discord-0.0.17.deb`, and **not** `discord-ptb-0.0.29.deb`.

That's a risky way to install stuff, because dependencies from a random deb file always cause problems. I'd still try to install it, but I wouldn't be surprised if it fails. Since I am familiar with how deb files works, maybe I could pinpoint the dependency problems (e.g., the deb was made for Debian 10, not Debian 11), but that still doesn't solve it.

So I'd google for "chromebook discord", which finds e.g. [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/discord-desktop/keldmkejekdkhdafcidopcdjlpgecghm), and then try to install this one instead of fiddling with a deb that's not working for my distro.

Comment: How do I get the package manager?

Comment: Start by editing the question and describing how you installed "Linux" on the Chromebook, and which distro you chose.

Comment: distro?
Sorry I'm kinda new lol

Comment: You did *something* to get "Linux" on your Chromebook. There are multiple ways to do that, so we don't know what you ended up with. Please edit your question and describe in sufficient detail what you did. In particular, there are different [Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) with different package managers, and we need to know which one you have.

Comment: Please also mention **which package or application** you want to install. Or what the name of the `.deb` file you downloaded is.

Comment: Done. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The authors of the Discord app seem to have chosen to depend on the `libappindicator1` package, which was removed from Debian in September 2021:

https://tracker.debian.org/news/1257945/removed-0492-8-from-unstable/

Debian 11 has transitioned to the upstream-supported `libayatana-appindicator` package instead:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895037

The `libappindicator1` package was still available in Debian 10, but no more in Debian 11.

However, if you are willing to risk using old libraries, you could load the packages `libappindicator1` and its dependency `libindicator7` from Debian 10, install them using e.g. `dpkg -i libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb` and then let `apt` or `aptitude` resolve any missing dependencies.

Since it's no different from having upgraded from Debian 10 to 11 with a few old libraries left over because of dependencies by third-party software, it might work.

Download links are at the bottom of the respective package info pages:

https://packages.debian.org/oldstable/libappindicator1

https://packages.debian.org/oldstable/libindicator7

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up finding Discord Beta in the chrome web store, because nothing that you guys suggested was working. Thanks for helping though!